How to enable "IsPriorityRecord" field on contact
I can see a field called "IsPriorityRecord" in a customer org but not in my scratch org. Contact object field reference doc just states it was added in v59.0, can anyone please mention how to enable that?

The IsPriorityRecord field is associated with the UserPrioritizedRecord object, which represents records that users flag as important for tracking in pipeline and intelligence views and filters.
To enable the IsPriorityRecord field in your scratch org, you may need to contact Salesforce Customer Support for assistance, as it might be related to features like Pipeline Inspection, Account Intelligence, Contact Intelligence, or Lead Intelligence, which may not be enabled by default in all orgs.

any official link/source of this?
